# can we insert a ' VBA Compound File ' containing its codes in streams into an access database to replace its Inbuilt one?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been searching a method to create access macros programmatically from VC++ .

I got very few information.One of which is that MS-Access  contains its "VBA code" in an OLE file which itself is stored in a table called " MSyAccesssStorage ".

I have a compound file stream of "VBA code"  and i need to insert it into a  database .

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

NO , we cant do it .I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the version control primitive: Application.LoadFromText to load VBA code into a project.